Test de scanner en java
comento mi problema al que no he podido solucionar por si alguien puede ayudarme. No creo que sea necesario enseñar codigo pero si lo necesitan lo envio.
Mi problema es el siguiente
Quiero hacer varios tests unitarios de metodos que utilizan el scanner (System.in), el problema se da cuando al ejecutar estos tests individualmente no fallan, pero al ejecutarlos en grupo si y me tira esta exception NoSuchElementException, no se me ocurre el porque de esto, si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradeceria. Saludos
Agrego codigo y un poco de informacion para que se entienda mejor,
el metodo a testear es colocarNave el cual llama a pedirCoordenadas (aqui esta el input del usuario)
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        tablero = new Tablero(10,10);
        buque = new Buque();
        acorazado = mock(Acorazado.class);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        System.setIn(System.in);
    }
    @Test
    @DisplayName("GIVEN a ship WHEN colocarNave() THEN return true")
    public void colocarNave () {//barco en lugar adecuado

        //coloco buque en 0,0
        String simulatedInput = "0\n0\n";
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedInput.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);

        boolean result = tablero.colocarNave(buque);

        for(int i=0; i<buque.getVida(); i++){
            Assertions.assertNotNull(tablero.getMatriz()[i][0]);
        }
        Assertions.assertTrue(result);

    }

public boolean colocarNave(Nave nave) {
        // solo rellena si el barco entra y no esta ocupado ese lugar
        Coordenada coord = pedirCoordenadas();

        if(!entraElBarco(nave, coord) || estaOcupado(nave, coord)) {
            return false;
        }

        rellenar(nave, coord);
        return true;
    }

public Coordenada pedirCoordenadas() {
        Coordenada coordenada = new Coordenada();
        Scanear scanear = Scanear.getInstance();
        Scanner scanner = scanear.getScanner();

        try{
            do {
                System.out.print("Ingrese fila: ");
                coordenada.setFila(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.print("Ingrese columna: ");
                coordenada.setColumna(scanner.nextInt());
                if (!validarCoordenadas(coordenada)) {
                    System.out.println("Error: Coordenadas fuera de rango. Por favor, reingrese.");
                }
            } while (!validarCoordenadas(coordenada));
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error, debe ingresar un numero entero");
            scanner.nextLine();
            return pedirCoordenadas();
        }

        return coordenada;
    }


Es necesario mostrar código:¿ estás usando mocks para simular System.in? ¿Estás vaciando el buffer para que cada test se inicie con el scanner esperando un input? Es complicado ayudarte si no podemos ver qué has hecho mal

Hola Facu, bienvenido, probablemente, el problema sea que no vacias el bufer, después de el test de cada función, vacia el bufer y se arreglará.

Hola, agradezco las respuestas, en cuanto a como simulo el Sysyem.in, no no he utilizado mocks sino una simulacion seteando el input como mostrare en la imagen, contestando lo relacionado con el bufer, he proado hacer un tearDown en los tets vaciando el buffer pero no funciona tampoco, no se si quizas estoy vaciando mal el buffer.

Hola de nuevo, estás vaciando el buffer, dentro del catch, osea, si no arroja un error, no lo vacia.
